# HDD not in /media/usr, Gparted "Physical block is 2048 but linux is 512" and kernel does not get the memo

Tags: partitioning, kernel, hard-drive, disk, drive

new in this Linux thing, if in any of my assumptions I'm mistaken please correct me I'm trying to learn how these things work.
So, as far as I understand, *other* drivers that aren't the main one should show up in /media/'myuser'/.

I have an external hard drive that shows there however my internal one does not. I've tried to mount UN-mount, followed a few of the main posts telling me what to do and they haven't worked so far. I do not remember winch posts is but if it is necessary I'll hunt then down, I'm a little untidy for googling stuff

First and second warning show at the beginning, third usually shows when trying to format the drive but now it showed up immediately. Yes I rebooted.

Any help is appreciated.

[First warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dKfw.png)

[Second warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElfFY.png)

[Third warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bIyO.png)

Comment: It’s not clear what your question is. I’d guess you want to partition one of your drives. External USB devices are mounted as you mention. Internal SATA connected drives are not mounted automatically unless configured to do so in the /etc/fstab file. Before making partition changes with GParted the drive should be unmounted. You can list all connected drives and their current mountpoints with “lsblk” in a terminal

Comment: I want the error to stop showing up. As clarification I wanted to know if the internal HDD not showing in /media is normal.

Comment: Which bs parameter worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article here would seem to answer your question https://codeyarns.com/2017/02/04/gparted-block-size-warning/

**Note that this solution will wipe all the data on the entire disk so you need a backup to preserve it. I also suspect there is a typo in the article it makes more sense to me for the bs=2048 parameter to be bs=512**

I don’t have an easy way to test this so if you have no data on the disk just see which works

Have copied it below to preserve the answer.

---

** GParted block size warning**

Problem
I opened GParted to look at the partition information of my drives. It popped up this strange warning:

The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes
I figured out that this error was about a USB thumb drive that was plugged into my computer. That USB drive was working fine and I could mount and read its files. So, what is this warning and how to fix it?

Solution
Turns out that the block size for this drive was set to 2048 bytes. It should have been 512 bytes. Its disk size was also appearing 4 times larger in GParted!

On thinking further about this, I remembered that this drive had been formatted as a bootable media to install Ubuntu using GNOME Disks as described here. That disk writer must have erroneously set the block size of this drive as 2048 bytes.

Changing back the block size to 512 was easy:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=2048 count=1
```

Replace /dev/sdc with the device ID for your USB thumb drive.

** Note that this command completely destroys all your data on the drive**.